# Node.js functions, objects and variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, socket.io, anonymous-function

I've just started with javascript and im still trying to get my head around how it works.

Can you explain why this works

```
serialPort.on("open", function () {
    console.log('open');
    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('data received: ' + data);
        //socket.emit('test', { arduinotest: 'Arduino Connected'});
    });  
});
```

and this doesn't, i get a "data is not defined error"

```
serialPort.on("open", function () {
    console.log('open');
    serialPort.on('data', received(data));  
});

function received(data) {
    console.log('data received: ' + data);
    //socket.emit('test', { arduinotest: 'Arduino Connected'});
}
```

How should I be separating my functions out as i don't like having lots of nested functions?

Here is my whole code

```
var app = require('express')()
    , server = require('http').createServer(app)
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
    , SerialPort  = require('serialport').SerialPort;

//SERIAL
var portName = '/dev/ttyACM0';
var serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, {
    baudRate: 115200,
    dataBits: 8,
    stopBits: 1,
    parity: 'none',   
});

serialPort.on("open", function () {
    console.log('open');
    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('data received: ' + data);
        //socket.emit('test', { arduinotest: 'Arduino Connected'});
    });  
});

//SERVER
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    socket.emit('test', { servertest: 'Server Connected' });
    socket.on('value', function (data){
        switch(data.key)
        {
        case "Right":
            if(data.state == "True")
            {
                serialPort.write("d180\n");
                console.log("test RT");
            }
            else if(data.state == "False")
            {
                serialPort.write("d90\n");
                console.log("test RF");
            }      
            break;
        case "Left":
            if(data.state == "True")
            {
                serialPort.write("d0\n");
                console.log("test LT");
            }
            else if(data.state == "False")
            {
                serialPort.write("d90\n");
                console.log("test LF");
            }      
            break;
        case "Up":
            if(data.state == "True")
            {
                serialPort.write("s0\n");
                console.log("test UT");
            }
            else if(data.state == "False")
            {
                serialPort.write("s90\n");
                console.log("test UF");
            }      
            break;
        case "Down":
            if(data.state == "True")
            {
                serialPort.write("s180\n");
                console.log("test DT");
            }
            else if(data.state == "False")
            {
                serialPort.write("s90\n");
                console.log("test DF");
            }      
            break;
        }
    });
});

server.listen(9081, '192.168.1.158');
```

How should i be accessing my socket object from within my serial port code (commented out line)?

Thanks for helping with my understanding

Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second example you've written `serialPort.on('data', received(data));` which will invoke the `received` function immediately, and pass the result to the second argument of the `on` listener.

Instead, you simply want to do `serialPort.on('data', received);` which passes the `received` function itself, meaning the listener can invoke it when ready.

Comment: Thanks, that's helped to clear things up. Im finding it quite hard to understand how javascript works coming from a "traditional" C# background

Comment: Just always keep in mind that "everything is an object" which can be assigned to a variable, even functions. It'll all fall into place :)

Answer (score 2):

To extend [Graham's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090388/node-js-functions-objects-and-variables/15090506#15090506) good answer. It is possible to send a callback that "takes parameters" by simply making a function that return a function. Here is how:

```
serialPort.on('data', received(data));

received = function(data){
  return function(){
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

For your other questions:

**How should I be separating my functions out as i don't like having lots of nested functions?**
It is normal to have a lot of callbacks when writing a node application, this is how it was designed. Just separate you logic into main actions. For example, lets say that you want to save something in the database:

```
function createBobAndSave(){
  var bob - new Bob();
  bob.save(function(err,savedBob){
    console.log(savedBob.id)
  });
}
```

**How should i be accessing my socket object from within my serial port code (commented out line)?**
You don't since socket in not within the client's socket scope. You can still use the sockets object to send data to all socket.io clients.

Comment: I want to send data to my client when my serial port receives data though, so it seems like i need to have a function that's called by the  serialport.on('data', received but passed the socket?? Im sure im still looking at this the wrong way round?